# Ionic navigate from Tab C to tab B > Child B1 result in No Back button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I use Ionic Framework and Tabs.

I would like to navigate from **Tab C** to **Tab B > Child B1** and it results in No Back button (to B view).

I used `href`, `ui-sref` and `state.go()` method ... always the same ! No back button.

```
$scope.gogo = function(){
    $state.go('tab.recap', {chatId: 2});
};
```

With `<button ng-click="gogo()">Go yeahhhh</button>`

**OR**

```
<a ui-sref="tab.recap({postId:2})">aze</a>
```

**OR**

```
<a href="#/tab/projets/2">aze</a>
```

And this is how I route:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('tab.accueil', {
        url: '/accueil',
        views: {
            'tab-accueil': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-accueil.html',
                controller: 'AccueilCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.projets', { // TAB B
        url: '/projets',
        views: {
            'tab-projets': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-projets.html',
                controller: 'ProjetsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('tab.recap', { // TAB B1
        url: '/projets/:chatId',
        views: {
            'tab-projets': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/recap.html',
                controller: 'RecapCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('tab.fiche', { // TAB B2
        url: '/projets/:chatId/:ficheId',
        views: {
            'tab-projets': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/fiche.html',
                controller: 'FicheCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('tab.notifications', { // TAB C
        url: '/notifications',
        views: {
            'tab-notifications': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/tab-notifications.html',
                controller: 'NotificationsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    ....
```

**EDIT :** I understand now that it's normal ! It doesn't have to be a Back button when I do that. **But how can I manually check if there is no Back button and put it one manually ?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default behaviour by adding the `<ion-navbar>//do what you want here</ion-navbar>` directive in your template, This post discusses more about the [topic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation). I haven't worked with ionic in sometime but the last I did, just doing the above made it work. Let me know how it goes, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i'm trying whithout success to do that : 
When I navigate from view C to view B1, I'm looking for **$ionicHistory.backView().stateName** in this B1 view. (In normal way it's "tab.projets")

```
    if($ionicHistory.backView().stateName != "tab.projets")
    { 
       $scope.display_custom_back_button = true;
    }
```

**It works (it detects correctly) but how can I display My custom back button in my view now ?**

```
<ion-view view-title="{{chat.name}}">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <img ng-src="{{chat.face}}" style="width: 64px; height: 64px">
    <p>
      <a href="#/tab/projets/{{chat.id}}/1111"> {{chat}} {{chat.lastText}}</a>
    </p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```